# Why do the height and width settings in react-webcam become reversed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam

I am using react-webcam configured as follows.

```
<Webcam
          audio={false}
          screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
          videoConstraints={{
            facingMode: "environment",
            width: cameraSize.width,
            height: cameraSize.height,
          }}
          width={props.width + "px"}
          height={props.height + "px"}
  />
```

In chrome on desktop (regardless of screen aspect ratio), the size is set in `videoConstraints`, but in Android and iOS, the cameraSize.width and cameraSize.height values are set reversed when the camera is in **portrait** orientation. (It's okay if it's in landscape orientation.)

Example:
cameraSize.width=768px, cameraSize.height=1920px, but actually width=1920px, height=768px.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem still. I'm considering detecting if it is a mobile browser and flip the aspect ratio programatically.

Would be great if anyone has figured out a better way of doing this.

Comment: Right now this answer isn't very detailed. Can you demonstrate how to flip the aspect ration? Otherwise this reads far more like a comment. Comments are not valid for answers, so you may wish to remove the "I'm getting the same..." and "Would be great if anyone has figured out ..." from your answer as those parts risk this being deleted for not being an answer.